# How to use setWebhook in Telegram with self certificates on Windows 7 and PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, telegram, apache2.4, telegram-bot

I'm quite a newbye in Telegram and I'm trying moving my first steps with it.

I've found a good tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJBYojK7DO4: I've configured my Apache 2.4 with PHP and SSL and all works fine, also the samples in the tutorial.

Troubles are using the setWebhook method .... when I try to put in my browser

```
https://api.telegram.org/<my_bot_code>/setWebHook?url=https://localhost/Telegram/MyYouTubeTutorialBot/YouTubeTutorialBot.php
```

the response is

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Error: Bad webhook: Error: Ip is reserved"}
```

Note that I'm using a self generated certificate ....

I've found in the api Telegram documentation (ref. https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#i-39m-having-problems-with-webhooks), that

"*..... To use a self-signed certificate, you need to upload your public key certificate using the certificate parameter in setWebhook. Please upload as InputFile, sending a String will not work.*"

I don't understand how to upload my public key certificate file .... any examples somewhere?

The problem could be because I'm using ***localhost*** and the default IP address ***127.0.0.1*** for my local Apache? Should I change my IP address using the current one that change every time I connect to the web (I'm using a internet key to connect me to the web .....)?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can't use localhost because 127.0.0.1 is only reachable from your inner computer. Telegram servers can't reach it.

Answer (score 8):

your local machine is not accessible over Internet by `localhost` or your local IP  (`127.0.0.1`) or local network IP (`192.168.1.2`) 
each machine has it self's `localhost` so telegram's servers localhost is different with your's
 
you should to use a `web hosting` or `VPS` to run your script and use its address
I know a free developer VPS : [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

Answer (score 8):

use following simple html code

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOCKEN>/setwebhook" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Certificate to upload:
    <input type="file" name="certificate" id="fileToUpload">
 URL: <input type="text" name="url"  value="https://<YOURWEBSITE>/<YOUR_PHP_URL>"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Certificate" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is simple post form , so you can upload the certificate to the telegram bot, just replace it with your bot information

Comment: brilliant. Thanks

Comment: <YOUR_PHP_URL> url to what?(file, action)

Answer (score 2):

The following library allows you to easily do that (and quickly set up a bot):

https://github.com/auino/php-telegram-bot-library

It essentially calls Telegram's `setWebhook` function/page, passing the self-signed certificate as a file, via a `POST` request:

```
$data = array("url"=>$YOURCALLBACKURL,"certificate"=>"@$CERTIFICATEFILE");
$telegramurl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/setWebhook";
// now you have to make a request on $telegramurl passing $data via POST (e.g. using curl library)
```

If you want to use `php-telegram-bot-library`, you can easily set it up through the install.php file, or using the following code (it works on Linux, it should work too on Windows systems):

```
$bot = new telegram_bot($TOKEN);
$bot->set_webhook($WEBHOOKURL, $SSLCERTIFICATEFILE);
```