# i am getting an error when i tried to set webhook for telegram

Tags: php, webhooks, telegram-bot

I want to set webhook for telegram for certain user input so that telegram replied automatically to predefined question and I am able to write the program which is running perfectly fine, but when I tried to set webhook for that program it is showing an error:

```
{
   "ok": false,"error_code": 400,"description": "Bad Request: bad webhook: Ip is reserved"
}
```

I tried to set webhook like that:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setwebhook?url=https://localhost/Manisha/bot.php
```

Comment: May be helpful for you:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378216/how-to-use-setwebhook-in-telegram-with-self-certificates-on-windows-7-and-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a **publically available URL** that the Telegram servers can reach. `http://localhost/` is not public.

You are trying to make an HTTP request to *the computer the bot is running on*.

This isn't your server, it is Telegram's server. It doesn't work because:

- Your PHP isn't installed on it
- Telegram won't let your bot go poking at their internal servers

Comment: then how can i do it and is there any publically available URL / server which i can use for my work ?

Comment: Rent a VPS or something.